# Parsing issues while parsing xml response android

Tags: android

Xml response is like , but in one tag , the text is  this:

```
<Description>
    &lt;center&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span&gt;Warehouse / Building Maintenance&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/center&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
    &lt;br /&gt;
    &lt;strong&gt;&lt;span&gt;I&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;span&gt;mmediate openings available in the local Perris area for warehouse/building building maintenance positions. &lt;br /&gt;
    &lt;br /&gt;
    &lt;strong&gt;Job Description:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
    &lt;/span&gt;
    &lt;ul&gt;
        &lt;li&gt;&lt;span&gt;Associates will be responsible to define pieces of equipment that will paralyze operations if they fail, and plan whatever level of preventative maintenance necessary. &lt;br /&gt;
        &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
        &lt;li&gt;&lt;span&gt
......
similar text
......
</Description>
```

I can't able to parse it in proper way.

I tried using `Jsoup.parse((nodeValue))`

and `Html.fromHtml(String)` also `URLEncoder.encode(String)`

but its returning simple `&` symbol thats it.

How to parse this type of response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its returning only `&` symbol , that's because the `nodelist` item returns only single value.

After using like this:

```
NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();

                    System.out.println("nodefstnm"+fstNm.getLength());

                    for(int j=0;j<fstNm.getLength();j++) {
                       String val = ((Node) fstNm.item(j)).getNodeValue();
                       nodeValue=nodeValue.concat(val);
                    }
```

and then parsing with `Jsoup`., returns what I want.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution could be applying replaceAll("`&lt;`", "<").replaceAll("`&gt;`", ">") if API methods aren't working, but arent you supposed to use [Html.toHtml(string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml%28android.text.Spanned%29) when you have stuff encoded and want it to become real html ?

Comment: you mean the full string is replaced by & ?